# Insert data using INSERT INTO command.

Tags: php, mysql, sql, database

I have two table name users and users_images. Both table have the value of userId. like
**My user table**

---

```
|   userId    |    userName    |    user_address    |
|    2    |    John    |    CN-2, UK    |
|    3    |    Amit    |    India    |
|    4    |    David    |    Us    |
|    5    |    Shan    |    Canada    |
.
.
...... and so on
```

---

```
|    125000    |    Naved    |    Ukran    |
```

**and my images table contain userid and Image name.

Now I want to merge ImageName field to user table without using any loop (I want to do it with single query (I have millions of records and I will have to do it many times to create temorary table) )

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
update users u
set
  u.imageName = (
       select imageName 
       from users_images i 
       where i.userid = u.userid GROUP BY u.userId )
```

Comment: I see you edited my query because you have multiple images. I removed `DISTINCT`, because you don't need it. MySQL automatically selects a single imageName for the userid you group by. In other databases you would need to use a function like `min(imageName)` to select a single image name.

Comment: And of course, you will have only one image left per user, so basically you will loose data when you remove the images from `users_images`, because not all previous user images will be stored.

Answer (score 0):

I think you can use Update for this like:

```
UPDATE Users
SET ImageName =
  (SELECT ImageName
   FROM UserImages
   WHERE UserImages.UserID = Uers.UserID)
```

Please take a backup of your database first

Comment: actually problem was I had more than one image for some user.. but I got solution by just adding GROUP BY in your query

Answer (score 0):

you could use [ON DUPLICATE KEY](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/insert-on-duplicate.html)
for instance:

```
INSERT INTO table (a,b,c) VALUES (1,2,3)
  ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE c=c+1;
```